# Get information from Blender in C++ (DeviceContext, RenderContext, Scene-Informations, ...)

Tags: c++, c, console-application, blender

I got an 3D-Scene loaded into Blender. Now I want to get some information like objects in scene, camera perspective and so on. Furthermore I want to get the `opengl` device context and render context. Something like a pointer on a structure.

Is it possible to get these information with an external console-application written in c/c++?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to read some data, you can write an exporter. I wrote [GLrawd](https://github.com/GoranM/glrawd) to export some basic scene data for my OpenGL apps, so you can take a look at that.

There is also a "[readblend](http://code.google.com/p/gamekit/source/browse/trunk/bullet/Extras/readblend/?r=40)" library that you can use.

If you're looking to actually control a blender scene from some external application, I think you'll have to use sockets to communicate the desired commands. In blender, you can set up the receiving side as a simple python script.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for that advice. I'm looking forward to solve this problem. If I find a solution, I share it here.